# Fullcalendar 1 day event displaying in 2 days when week option selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

My requirement is to show an event with time interval. When I try to use this code it seems not working properly. May be I am wrong at timezone selection but not getting exactly what need to do. Please help.

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-02-12',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            timeFormat: 'h:mm a',
            //timezone: "local",
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2016-02-09T13:00:00-00:00',
                    end: '2016-02-09T14:00:00-00:00'
                }
            ]
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried by configuring timezone option?

Comment: @ChintanMirani: I got the issue. It is not related to TimeZone.

Comment: Issue: **fullcalendar-rails** gem has issue in its JS

I just took the fullcalendar JS from [Full Calendar Download](http://fullcalendar.io/download/)

Comment: Oh! Chetan you! Nice to see you here. World is so tiny. BTW did you find solution?

Comment: @ChintanMirani, Yes I got the solution added in above comment :)